# Гистограмма html jq

Tags: html, javascript, гистограммы

Всем привет.

В общем, есть код, суть которого создать гистограмму, а данные берутся из jq. Я написал кое-что, но - вот беда - не работает.

Понимаю, код может быть косячный, и вообще чушь, но я учусь, строго не судите и подскажите, что сделать.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsu34c1h/

Answer (score 1):

Тебе принципиально самому хочется создать?
Так то [готовых решений](http://google.gik-team.com/?q=jquery+histogram) куча
В частности [вот](http://www.highcharts.com/) хороший бесплатный чарт

Comment: конечно, лучше самому) тем более, там все на англ., а у меня с ним плохо)